# Advice on installing vertical blinds

Tags: mounting, blinds, sliding-glass-door

In the back of my house I am attempting to install vertical blinds. Unfortunately the blinds are longer than the door frame and this has led to a differing of opinions on what to do. My first inclination was to install the brackets 3 inches above the door frame, but all of the blinds and curtains in our house go across the top of the window frame and this could lead to the setup looking rather out of place. Does the internet hive mind have any thoughts on what I should do here? What occurs to me is:

1. Install the vertical blind well above the door frame and live with the weird presentation/orientation of the blinds.
2. Install the vertical blinds at the height of the door frame and let the shades drag along the floor (this seems like the worst option of the 3) when they are open/closed.
3. Install the vertical blinds at the height of the door frame and then cut the shades to the right height. I assume scissors will be able to cut through the shades since they do look very thin, but I am always rather quizzical about disfiguring objects in case down the road I wish they were longer.

I am just looking for what other people would do in this situation.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion and design sensibility. Both are off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you in the US? Did you buy your vertical blinds at a big box store? If so and if they're still stacked neatly in their packaging you can go to a big box hardware store and have them cut them the length you need. They can do a package of ten all at once with their equipment. If you didn't buy them there you can try and ask them to do it and perhaps offer a tip?

You do not want the vertical blinds dragging on the floor. They will look terrible and you won't be able to adjust them open and closed without creating a very unappealing effect.

I know what you mean about the different heights for window treatments looking out of place. In my home, we have a room with three windows that are the same height as the two pairs of patio sliding doors. For the windows we installed solar shades that are inside mount. For the patio doors we installed vertical blinds. I wanted to keep the height of all the window and door treatments the same so I kept the track just an inch above the doors. After I installed the track I measured the length from where the individual blinds would attach from the track to the floor. Then I subtracted a half inch. If i had carpeting I'd probably subtract 3/4 of an inch or a whole inch. After I had my length established I took my already purchased vertical blinds back to Home Depot to have them cut. They put the entire package of ten in a cutting device and cut them all at once. After installing them they look custom and very professional.

You can try cutting them by hand but they may not come out as nice and consistent looking.